# Pytorch ValueError: Optimizer got an empty parameter list with multiscale discriminator

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, discriminator

I am trying to make a GAN with a multiscale discriminator. How do I call the parameters of the discriminator if the discriminator is composed of three other discriminators?
Multiscale discriminator code:

```
class MultiscaleDiscriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, ndf=64, n_layers=3, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm2d,
                 use_sigmoid=False, num_D=3):
        super(MultiscaleDiscriminator, self).__init__()
        self.input_nc=input_nc
        self.ndf=ndf
        self.n_layers=n_layers
        self.norm_layer=norm_layer
        self.use_sigmoid=use_sigmoid
        self.num_D=num_D
        self.discriminators = []
        # instantiate the discriminators
        for i in range(self.num_D):
            self.discriminators.append(
                self.singleD_forward(int(input_nc / (2 ** i)))
            )
        self.downsample = nn.AvgPool2d(3, stride=2, padding=[1, 1], count_include_pad=False)
        self.inputs = [1, 1]

    def singleD_forward(self, input_nc):
        return NLayerDiscriminator(
            input_nc=input_nc,
            ndf=self.ndf,
            n_layers=self.n_layers,
            norm_layer=self.norm_layer,
            use_sigmoid=self.use_sigmoid)
       
    def forward(self, inputs):        
        is_conditioned = isinstance(inputs, list)

        if is_conditioned:
            (
                fake_or_real,
                condition,
            ) = inputs  # inputs is a tuple containing the generated images and the conditions
        else:
            fake_or_real = inputs
            condition = None
        outs = []
        features = []

        fake_or_real_i = fake_or_real
        condition_i = condition
        for i, discriminator in enumerate(self.discriminators):
            # compute value of the i-th discriminator
            out, feat = discriminator(
                [fake_or_real_i, condition_i]
                
            )

            # append output and features
            outs.append(out)
            features.extend(feat)
            # reduce input size
            if i != len(self.discriminators) - 1:
                fake_or_real_i = self.downsample(fake_or_real_i)
                condition_i = (
                    self.downsample(condition_i) if condition_i is not None else None
                )

        # handle output values
        if return_features:
            return outs, features
        return outs
             
# Defines the PatchGAN discriminator with the specified arguments.
class NLayerDiscriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, ndf=64, n_layers=3, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm2d, use_sigmoid=False, getIntermFeat=False):
        super(NLayerDiscriminator, self).__init__()
        self.getIntermFeat = getIntermFeat
        self.n_layers = n_layers

        kw = 4
        padw = int(np.ceil((kw-1.0)/2))
        sequence = [[nn.Conv2d(input_nc, ndf, kernel_size=kw, stride=2, padding=padw), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True)]]

        nf = ndf
        for n in range(1, n_layers):
            nf_prev = nf
            nf = min(nf * 2, 512)
            sequence += [[
                nn.Conv2d(nf_prev, nf, kernel_size=kw, stride=2, padding=padw),
                norm_layer(nf), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True)
            ]]

        nf_prev = nf
        nf = min(nf * 2, 512)
        sequence += [[
            nn.Conv2d(nf_prev, nf, kernel_size=kw, stride=1, padding=padw),
            norm_layer(nf),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True)
        ]]

        sequence += [[nn.Conv2d(nf, 1, kernel_size=kw, stride=1, padding=padw)]]

        if use_sigmoid:
            sequence += [[nn.Sigmoid()]]

        if getIntermFeat:
            for n in range(len(sequence)):
                setattr(self, 'model'+str(n), nn.Sequential(*sequence[n]))
        else:
            sequence_stream = []
            for n in range(len(sequence)):
                sequence_stream += sequence[n]
            self.model = nn.Sequential(*sequence_stream)

    def forward(self, input):
        if self.getIntermFeat:
            res = [input]
            for n in range(self.n_layers+2):
                model = getattr(self, 'model'+str(n))
                res.append(model(res[-1]))
            return res[1:]
        else:
            return self.model(input)
```

When I run:

```
    disc_A = MultiscaleDiscriminator(dim_A).to(device)
disc_A_opt = torch.optim.Adam(disc_A.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
```

I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 18
     14 disc_B = disc_B.apply(weights_init)
     16 gen_opt = torch.optim.Adam(list(gen_AB.parameters()) + list(gen_BA.parameters()), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
---> 18 disc_A_opt = torch.optim.Adam(disc_A.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
     20 disc_B_opt = torch.optim.Adam(disc_B.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
     22 '''
     23 # Feel free to change pretrained to False if you're training the model from scratch
     24 pretrained = False
   (...)
     37     disc_A = disc_A.apply(weights_init)
     38     disc_B = disc_B.apply(weights_init)'''

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\optim\adam.py:45, in Adam.__init__(self, params, lr, betas, eps, weight_decay, amsgrad, foreach, maximize, capturable, differentiable, fused)
     39     raise ValueError(f"Invalid weight_decay value: {weight_decay}")
     41 defaults = dict(lr=lr, betas=betas, eps=eps,
     42                 weight_decay=weight_decay, amsgrad=amsgrad,
     43                 maximize=maximize, foreach=foreach, capturable=capturable,
     44                 differentiable=differentiable, fused=fused)
---> 45 super().__init__(params, defaults)
     47 if fused:
     48     if differentiable:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\optim\optimizer.py:261, in Optimizer.__init__(self, params, defaults)
    259 param_groups = list(params)
    260 if len(param_groups) == 0:
--> 261     raise ValueError("optimizer got an empty parameter list")
    262 if not isinstance(param_groups[0], dict):
    263     param_groups = [{'params': param_groups}]

ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎